# Fijar valor de winworm combobox vinculado a un datatable

Tags: c#

Buen dia

Como puedo fijar un valor a un combobox que esta vinculado a un datatable:

Ej:

MiComboBoc.SelectedValue = "01"

Answer (score 0):

Esto fue la solución:

```
foreach (ComboboxItem cbi in CBAlmacenes.Items)
                        {
                            if (cbi.Value as String == row["CodAlmacen"].ToString())
                            {
                                CBAlmacenes.SelectedItem = cbi;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
```